# Building 32-bit CGAL with CMake: makes 64-bit binaries even though 32-bit specified?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, makefile, cgal

I'm on Windows 7. I have installed 32-bit CGAL 4.6.2 and Boost on my system. I've also successfully built Boost and tested that it works (the simple regex program).

Now I'm trying to build CGAL using CMake as instructed by [this tutorial](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2012/07/18/setup-cgal-in-windows-7-step-by-step-tutorial/). The only thing I'm adding to that tutorial, is that I'm introducing the `-m32` flag in ALL of the flags; static linker, dynamic linker, exe linker, c and c++ compilers. Configuring and then generating goes fine, and I get the CMake output:

```
== Setting paths ==
Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-4.6.2-x86
Packagenames: CGAL-4.6.2-x86
== Setting paths (DONE) ==

== Generate version files ==
CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=4
CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=6
CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=2
CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=11
CGAL_SOVERSION     =11.0.0
CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
Building shared libraries
Targetting MinGW Makefiles
Using E:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe compiler.
USING CMake version: 2.8.8
System: Windows
USING GCC_VERSION = '5.1.0'
Using gcc version 4 or later. Adding -frounding-math
== Generate version files (DONE) ==

== Set up flags ==
Build type: Release
USING CXXFLAGS = ' -frounding-math -m32 -O3 -DNDEBUG -m32'
USING LDFLAGS = '-m32 -m32'
== Set up flags (DONE) ==

== Detect external libraries ==
External libraries supported: GMP;MPFR;ZLIB;OpenGL;LEDA;MPFI;RS;RS3;OpenNL;Eigen3;BLAS;LAPACK;QGLViewer;ESBTL;Coin3D;NTL;IPE
Preconfiguring library: GMP ...
GMP has been preconfigured:
  UseGMP-file:      
  GMP include:      e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6.2-x86/auxiliary/gmp/include
  GMP libraries:    e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6.2-x86/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libgmp-10.dll
  GMP definitions:  
USING GMP_VERSION = '5.0.1'
Preconfiguring library: MPFR ...
MPFR has been preconfigured:
  UseMPFR-file:      
  MPFR include:      e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6.2-x86/auxiliary/gmp/include
  MPFR libraries:    e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/CGAL-4.6.2-x86/auxiliary/gmp/lib/libmpfr-4.dll
  MPFR definitions:  
USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.0.0'
Boost version: 1.59.0
Found the following Boost libraries:
  thread
  system
Boost include:     e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/boost_1_59_0-x86
Boost libraries:   optimized;e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/boost_1_59_0-x86/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mgw51-mt-1_59.a;debug;e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/boost_1_59_0-x86/stage/lib/libboost_thread-mgw51-mt-d-1_59.a;optimized;e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/boost_1_59_0-x86/stage/lib/libboost_system-mgw51-mt-1_59.a;debug;e:/Users/Bombax/Cpp/Libraries/boost_1_59_0-x86/stage/lib/libboost_system-mgw51-mt-d-1_59.a
Boost definitions: 
USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.59.0'
== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==

== Write compiler_config.h ==
== Write compiler_config.h (DONE) ==

== Generating build files ==
Configuring libCGAL
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Core' detected
Configuring libCGAL_Core
Requested component: MPFR
Requested component: GMP
libCGAL_Core is configured
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_ImageIO' detected
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt3' detected
Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt4' detected
Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt3;CGAL_Qt4' detected
== Generating build files (DONE) ==

Configuring done
Generating done
```

CMake generates a CodeBlocks project for me, but I've never successfully built using it because it never seems to be able to find `make.exe` no matter how I move and rename `mingw32-make.exe`. Anyway, in the past, I was able to build CGAL manually, and I simply copied `mingw32-make.exe` into my CGAL folder, I then ran in that folder from command line:

```
mingw32-make.exe -s -f Makefile all
```

But then I get this output!

```
Scanning dependencies of target CGAL
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/CGAL/CMakeFiles/CGAL.dir/all_files.cpp.obj
[ 50%] Building RC object src/CGAL/CMakeFiles/CGAL.dir/CGAL_verinfo.rc.obj
Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\libCGAL.dll
E:/PROGRA~3/CODEBL~1/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../
86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `CMakeFile
\CGAL.dir/objects.a(CGAL_verinfo.rc.obj)' is incompatible with i386 output
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
src\CGAL\CMakeFiles\CGAL.dir\build.make:107: recipe for target 'bin/libCGAL.dll
 failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [bin/libCGAL.dll] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:185: recipe for target 'src/CGAL/CMakeFiles/CGAL.dir/all'
ailed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [src/CGAL/CMakeFiles/CGAL.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:112: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

I thought I had done everything correctly so that CMake generates 32-bit binaries instead of 64 bit binaries, yet the error suggests the generated binaries are 64 bit? How can I fix this problem, do I need another option in CMake or...?

Comment: Isn't it faster to add -m32 to CXX instead of plenty of *_FLAGS variables? Or does cmake fail to handle it?

Comment: It might be, haha, but I wanted to make absolutely sure this was not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Apparently `windres.exe` runs in 64 bit mode as well or whatever so I needed to add some flags before configuring with CMake. Specifically, to the `CMAKE_RC_FLAGS` I needed to add `--output-format=coff --target=pe-i386` for my Windows 7 system.